# Android : restrict the input to numbers and periods

Tags: android

I am trying to get the IP address as a string value from the EditText, I want to restrict the user input to only numbers and periods..

I really have no idea about this. Is there a way to restrict the keypad to only show numbers and period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [official doc on Android on keyboardInput](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/style), but basically you can modify the `android:inputType` property like this:

```xml
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="phone"
        ... />
```

Here's a [detailed list](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) of what you can modify in the field

"phone" input type only content numbers and some characters.

Comment: this isn't right. "numberDecimal" is only support decimals . that means i can only use 1 period . but im trying to get ipaddress as input.

Comment: Do you check the url I left to see (for yourself) other inputTypes and see what suits you best? - try with textUri, I edited my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks I only checked one link, I didn't see the 2nd one, the "phone" input type fits my task. thanks for your support